# I am trying to creating a polling app on the mean stack. I think my routing is messed up but I am not sure

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, mean-stack, mean.io

I am trying to create the polling app described in this [tutorial here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-nodejs-polling-app/index.html).

I have step 2 finished, and I am about to start step 3(once my application is running properly) which is to incorporate the DB portion. My application is not behaving like the application listed in the tutorial currently though.

I have scanned my code numerous times and debugged it and still cant seem to catch what is throwing it off. When I run the application it runs fine, but none of my partials are being displayed only what is provided in the inital index.html view, so it is simply showing my blank navbar.

I have provided my git [repository](https://github.com/fredk212/PollApp). If anyone has a moment and can take a look at it. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: I submitted a [Pull Request](https://github.com/fredk212/PollApp/pull/1) with the full fix for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the key things I fixed in my [pull request](https://github.com/fredk212/PollApp/pull/1):

1. You need to include `angular-route.js` as a separate file now, and have your module depend on `ngRoute`.
2. You were missing quotes around the first `$routeProvider` in the following line:

   `.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){`
3. You now need to register controllers using a name (string) with the module, rather than using global functions.

   `app.controller('ControllerName', function ($scope, ...) { ... });`
4. You also forgot to actually reference a few of the JS files you need in `index.html` using `<script>` tags.

There are other small things, but see the PR for the full details. I also changed the way bower components are done.

Comment: Hey greg thank you so much. Your answer obviously worked, and your explanation was more than I could have asked for. You are an angel friend.